# How to properly destroy Paper.js Scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory, memory-leaks, paperjs

I'm using multiple Paper.js canvases by creating a new scope for each of them. The site is driven with AJAX, so I have to destroy unneeded instances when I change the subpages. Unfortunately, there's no such thing as `paper.destroy()` method that I could call to clear the memory when I no longer need an instance of paper scope. And after I call `view.remove()`, my console gets full of errors from paper.js core, as the scope keeps trying to use it anyway.

To show you what I'm trying to do, here's a piece of code taken from the constructor:

```
this.paper = new paper.PaperScope;
this.paper.setup(this.canvas);
```

And that's how I tried to destroy the instance:

```
this.paper.view.remove();
```

And then I remove the `canvas` from DOM. After doing that, I keep getting the following error on console:

```
Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
```

Currently, the only solution I come up with is to reuse scopes and canvases instead of destroying them (using a pool of unused instances instead of constantly creating new ones), so I don't have a huge memory leak. Although that's not the perfect solution as I can't fully get rid of these instances.

So my question is: how to properly completely destroy paper.js instances to prevent memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `remove()` on `PaperScope` instance directly.

```
// get a reference to the canvas element
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
// init paper scope
var scope  = new paper.PaperScope;
scope.setup(canvas);

// here do what you want with the canvas

// clear scope
scope.remove();
// remove element
canvas.remove();

// clear variables so they can be garbage collected
canvas = null;
scope  = null;
```